# Pyrogram telegram poll : how to get the chosen option from user

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I created a telegram bot that sends quiz with pyrogram, but i want to get the user's answer using a method called Poll.chosen_option and then compare it with the correct answer!!
But this method returns None, Please how can i solve that and get what user chosen!
Here is my code:

```
@app.on_message(filters.private & filters.text)
async def my_quiz(client, message : Message):
    quiz() # function returns global vars question, answers, answersID
    result = await app.send_poll(chat_id=message.chat.id, question=question, options=answers, is_anonymous=False, type="quiz", correct_option_id=answerID)
    print(result.poll.chosen_option) # here it returns None, it should return the index of the answer that the user choose
```

Answer (score 0):

`result` will give you the return value of [`sendPoll`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendpoll) - immediately after the message has been sent and before the user could have a chance to vote on the poll.
You'll need to catch the poll answer event separately. TBH, I'm not familiar with pyrogram so I can't tell you how that's done in pyrogram.

Comment: I didn't know how to solve it, I found a method in pyrogram.raw.functions called GetPollResults but didn't know how to work with it

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem you can do like this

```
pool = None    
@app.on_message(filters.private & filters.text)
async def my_quiz(client, message : Message):
    glogal pool
    quiz() # function returns global vars question, answers, answersID
    pool = await app.send_poll(chat_id=message.chat.id, question=question, options=answers, is_anonymous=False, type="quiz", correct_option_id=answerID)
```

to get the result you have to pass to the function get_messages the chat_id and message id for the poll

```
@app.on_message(filters.command("result"))
async def get_result(app , message):
    result =  await app.get_messages(chat_id , poll.id)
    print(result.poll.chosen_option)
```